# WHy use a base view in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Why would one use a Base view in Django when this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

can be written as

```
def get(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

What is the advantage of the Base view vs the function view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All sorts of reasons.

1. You want to make use of a specialized view, like the `TemplateView` mentioned by @pythonista that makes it a lot easier for you to write your view.  e.g.,

   ```
   class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
       template_name = 'template.html'
   ```
2. You want to have some isolation when you have similar behavior.  For example, you want a class-based View to handle both the form rendering and the form post:

   ```
   class MyFormView(TemplateView):
       template_name = 'form.html'

       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           return super(MyFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs:
           value1 = request.POST.get('value1')
           value2 = request.POST.get('value2')
           # handle the post values
           return super(MyFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
   ```
3. You have  REST endpoint and you’d like to isolate all of the code for GET/POST/PUT/DELETE in a single class-based view.

   ```
       class RestEndpoint(View):
           def __init__(self):
               super(RestEndpoint, self).__init__()
               self.model = MyModel

           def get(request, n_id, *args, **kwargs):
               x = self.model.objects.get(id=n_id)
               return JsonResponse(x.to_json())

           def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
               data = json.loads(request.body)
               x = self.model(**data)
               x.save()
               return JsonResponse(x.to_json())

           def post(self, request, n_id, *args, **kwargs):
               data = json.loads(request.body)
               x = self.model.objects.get(id=n_id)
               for key, value in data.items():
                   setattr(x, key, value)
               x.save()
               return JsonResponse(x.to_json())

           def delete(self, request, n_id, *args, **kwargs):
               self.model.objects.filter(id=n_id).delete()
               return JsonResponse({})
   ```
4. You just prefer using classes instead of functions, e.g., so that you can create your own fun base views and reuse code with inheritance.